# Profile Card - placing image at the bottom center of my div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place my image at the bottom center, like this:

[image]

how do I make this happen?
so far I got this, this works for large screen but it's not responsive. Is there a way to make this responsive without having to change my css for every breakpoing ?

```css
.card-container{
  width: 20vw;
  height: 45vh;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-card{
  background-image: url(/images/bg-pattern-card.svg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0 ;
  position: relative;
}

.top-card img{
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  bottom: -40px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
      <div class="top-card">
        <img src="/images/image-victor.jpg" alt="icon" />
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-card">

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `justify-content: center` to center the image horizontally. Then `align-items: flex-end` to position the image at the bottom of the parent.

Then you can use `transform: translateY` to push the image down half of the image's own height.

```css
.card-container {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-card {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/900/300);
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.top-card img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  transform: translateY(45px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="top-card">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, Thank you!